# How to use set 2Checkout Authentication Headers?

Tags: node.js, 2checkout

I'm trying to use 2checkout REST API

https://knowledgecenter.2checkout.com/API-Integration/REST_5.0_Reference#/introduction/authentication/json-encoded-requests

Here's a snippet of how i try to request

```
const axios = require('axios')
const moment = require('moment')
const saltedMd5 = require('salted-md5');

let now = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS')
let vendorCode = '250207358831'

let toHash = vendorCode.length + vendorCode + now.length + now

let salt = '~0CSl)!M@4rZ|zX5QR&s'
const hash = saltedMd5(toHash, salt)

axios.get('https://api.2checkout.com/rest/5.0/subscriptions/?Email=customer%40email.com&AvangateCustomerReference=1234567&ExternalCustomerReference=abcdefg&Page=1&Limit=10&PurchasedBefore=2015-12-29&PurchasedAfter=2015-01-15&ExpireBefore=2016-05-22&ExpireAfter=2015-07-23&Type=regular&Aggregate=false', {
  headers: {
    'X-Avangate-Authentication': `code="${vendorCode}" date="${now}" hash="${hash}"`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(res => {
  console.log(res)
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
})
```

It returns status code 500. Does someone know how to retrieve subscriptions using the 2checkout API?

Comment: solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```js
class TwoCheckoutService {
    tco: {
        domain:string;
        apiUrl: string,
        apiUser:string,
        apiPass:string,
        sellerId:string,
        privateKey:string,
        secretKey:string,
        demo:boolean,
    };

    constructor(private userService: UserService) {
        this.tco = {=
            apiUrl: 'https://api.2checkout.com/rest/6.0',
            apiUser: "=",                              
            apiPass: "=",                              
            sellerId: "=",                                    
            privateKey: "=",     
            secretKey: "=",                                  
            demo: true,                                             
            // sandbox: false                                         
        };
    }

    private async _getAuthHeaders(): Promise<{[key:string]: string}> {

        var code = this.tco.sellerId;
        var date = moment().utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
        var stringToHash = code.toString().length + code + date.toString().length + date;
        var hmac = crypto.createHmac('md5', this.tco.secretKey);
        hmac.update(stringToHash, 'utf8');
        
        var hash  = hmac.digest('hex')
        var authHeader = `code="${code}" date="${date}" hash="${hash}"`

        return {
            'X-Avangate-Authentication': authHeader,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        };
    }

    async getProducts() {
        var url = this.tco.apiUrl + '/products/';
        var headers = await this._getAuthHeaders();
        console.log(headers);
        var res = await Axios.get(url, {
            headers: headers,
            params: {
                'Limit': 10,
                'Page': 1,
            },
            validateStatus: (status)=>true
        });

        if(res.status === 200) return res.data;
        return {
            error:  true,
            data: res.data,
            url: url,
            headers: headers
        }
    }
}
```

#This is an example in typescript nodejs
##requirements

- crypto
- axios
- 2checkout api credentials